# Update value in one column based on another value in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel with 10,000 rows and 2 columns (ID, Name)

Each ID has a corresponding name

ID | NAME
1  | John Smith
2  | Rob More
1  | John Smith
2  | Rob More
3  | Ben Jackson
3  | Ben Jackson

I would like to update the "NAME" column based on the value in the "ID" column.

If ID is 1, I would like to change the value of NAME column from John Smith to Ryan Smith. All the rows containing ID as 1 should be changed to Ryan Smith.

I wish to replace real values in the NAME column to some dummy values.

Comment: How many NAME-ID pairs are there? You might want to create a list and use `VLOOKUP` to assign the correct name to the ID.

Comment: There can be more than 10000 ID NAME pairs in the list. I wish to replace the real value of the NAME column with a dummy value for the corresponding ID

Comment: All the names needs to be replaced for all the corresponding IDs

Comment: Do you just wish to do ONE name replacement at a time, or do you have a list of replacement names to process?

Comment: I wish to create dummy names for the real names present under the NAME column. For each ID (that may repeat multiple times within the ID column), I would like to replace it with a dummy name (which can be any name)

Comment: How are the dummy names listed... in a range somewhere?

Comment: I have a list of dummy names that we can use

Comment: So you have TWO lists on a worksheet. Both lists have two columns (ID, Name). The first list has duplicate entries and you want to change the Name column values of the 1st list based on the ID matching in the 2nd list. Is this correct and are you open to a VBA solution?

Comment: I have two lists, one with ID and Real Name values and the other with only Dummy Name values. I am fine with a VBA solution but I am not an expert on the same.

Comment: Umm... Your second list has to have two columns as well, or this will never work. One column can be the dummy names. But the other column must be some value to match against the first list. The most logical value would be the ID, but this other column could also be composed of the Real Name. Either way, you must have this additional column and every dummy name must have a value in this corresponding column.. Do you have that?

Comment: Ok, I can create another list with ID | DUMMY NAME list where each unique ID has a DUMMY name associated with it. So we will have two lists, one with ID | REAL NAME and other with ID | DUMMY NAME. If we have two lists, then we can simple use VLOOKUP I believe, is it correct?

Comment: Ok sounds good. Let me try this. thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: There is still a "Dummy" issue. Do you want to show a "Dummy" name instead of a real name? So would you use the "Dummy" name as the value to lookup in your `vlookup()` formula?

Comment: Yes Davesexcel, I wish to show dummy name instead of a real name. Here is the solution. I removed all duplicates to give a list of unique IDs. I created fake names and assigned each ID a unique fake name. Then applied vlookup against the ID|Real Name list and replaced real names with fake names

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the screenshot below, I created a list of all the ID-NAME pairs. In the right box you can see, how the `VLOOKUP` function is used.

[image]